# Essa é uma boa forma de instanciar uma modal sem deixar residuos no html?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap-3

A fase inicial do projeto que estou trabalhando está quase acabando, e estou ajustando as coisas feitas de modo não muito bem feito (gambiarras).

Uma dessas coisas era que eu deixava dois elementos modais de residuo em meu `html` base pra usar eles nas respostas de requisições, achei isso muito ruim mas só agora pensei em modo de contornar isso.

São 3 funções dentro de uma pseudo-classe javascript:

```
function ajaxCall(functions, settings, values) {

    $(document).trigger("onRequireByAjax");

    $.ajax({
        type: settings['method'],
        url: "callers.php",
        data: {function: functions['function'], target: functions['target'], values},
        dataType: settings['dataType'],
        success: function (data)
        {
            if (functions['action'] === 'fill-element') {
                $('.' + functions['element']).html(data);
            }
            if (functions['action'] === 'fill-modal') {
                renderModal('modal-area', data['modal']);
                $('.' + data['modal']).modal('toggle');
                $('.modal').find('.modal-title').html(data['title']);
                $('.modal').find('.modal-body').html(data['body']);
                $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.' + data['modal'], function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

function renderModal(element, id) {
    var html = '' +
            '<div class="modal fade in ' + id + '" data-keyboard="alse" data-backdrop="static" id="full" tabindex=" - 1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">' +
            '<div class="modal-dialog modal-full">' +
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>' +
            '<h4 class="modal-title"></h4>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
    $('.' + element).append(html);
}

function destroyModal(id) {
    $('.' + id).remove();
}
```

O único residuo que tenho em meu `html` base é uma `div`:

```
<div class='modal-area'></div>
```

E pra disparar essa modal eu informo nos parâmetros do método ajaxCall:

```
        var functions = {
            function: 'navigation',
            target: target,
            layer: layer,
            action: 'fill-modal'
        };
        var settings = {
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        };
        var values = null;
        ajaxCall(functions, settings, values);
```

E com uma resposta como essa é definido o nome da modal e o conteúdo:

```
$rs = [
    'modal' => 'minha-modal',
    'title' =>'meu titulo',
    'body' => 'corpo da modal'
];
```

Dentro da função ajaxCall e dentro da chamada, existe um evento disparado em 'hidden.bs.modal' que remove o elemento que havia sido inserido anteriormente:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.' + data['modal'], function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

A pergunta foi grande mais a dúvida é simples:

- Essa é uma boa maneira de trabalhar com modais bootstrap sem deixar
  residuos ?
- Se não, qual poderia ser uma opção mais viável ?